# should I shift a dataset to use it for regression with LSTM?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Maybe this is a silly question but I didn't find much about it when I google it.

I have a dataset and I use it for regression but a normal regression with FFNN didn't worked so I thought why not try an LSTM since my data is time dependent I think because it was token from a vehicle while driving so the data is monotonic and maybe I can use LSTM in this Case to do a regression to predict a continuous value (if this doesn't make sense please tell me).

Now the first step is to prepare my data for using LSTM, since I ll predict the future I think my target(Ground truth or labels) should be shifted to the up, am I right?

So if I have a pandas dataframe where each row hold the features and the target(at the end of the row), I assume that the features should stay where they are and the target would be shifted it one step up so that the features in the first row will correspond to the target of the second row (am I wrong).

This way the LSTM will be able to predict the future value from those features.

I didn't find much about this in the internet so please can you provide me how can I do this with some Code?

I also know what I can use `pandas.DataFrame.shift` to shift a dataset but the last value will hold a NaN I think! how to deal with this? it would be great if you show me some examples or code.

Answer (score 0):

We might need a bit more information regarding the data you are using. Also, I would suggest starting with a more simple recurrent neural network before you start going for LSTMs. The way these networks work is by you feeding the first bit of information, then the next bit of information, then the next bit etc. Let's say that when you feed the first bit of information in, it occurs at time `t`, then the second bit of information is fed at time `t+1` ... etc. up until time `t+n`.

You can have the neural network output a value at **each** time step (so a value is outputted at time `t`, `t+1`... `t+n` after each respective input has been fed in). This is a many-to-many network. Or you can have the neural network output a value after **all** inputs have been provided (i.e. the value is outputted at time `t+n`). This is called a many-to-one network. What you need is dependednt on your use-case.

For example, say you were recording vehicle behaviour every 100ms and after 10 seconds (i.e. the 100th time step), you wanted to predict the likelihood that the driver was under the influence of alcohol. In this case, you would use a many-to-one network where you put in subsequent vehicle behaviour recordings at subsequent time steps (the first recording at time `t`, then the next recording at time `t+1` etc.) and then the final timestep has the probability value outputted.

If you want a value outputted after every time step, you use a many-to-many design. It's also possible to output a value every `k` timesteps.

Comment: thanks, yes I know that all but the question is, should I let my dataset the way it is now or should I shift it up or down? what I mean is when I use a Feed Forward NN, I should change nothing because I'm predicting present values but the LSTM predicted a future values and that is exactly what I mean with shifting the target values up and down. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you are trying to predict. Do you need a many-to-one or a many-to-many LSTM?

Comment: I have 5 feature and 1 output. the data was token while driving. the feature are speed, acceleration of the vehicle, timestamp, yaw rate and wheel angle and the output is the position at that time. the data is pandas dataframe where each row correspond to a time t. now if I want to use lstm I guess I must change my target (position) to be shifted to the future or am I wrong? If I let the dataset just like the way it is now, it doesn't make sense to use LSTM because there is no time shift, all the data are at time t or am I wrong?

Comment: I’ll rephrase my question, how many outputs do you want from the neural network, one at each time step? If so, I presume, then you don’t shift anything around and keep it as is. This is because the LSTM will learn to predict the position output for timestep ‘t+1’ given the position output of timestep ‘t’. The data is not all at time ‘t’, the first row is ‘t’, the second row is ‘t+1’, the third row is ‘t+2’ etc.

Comment: yes exactly you are right, the first row is t, second is t+1 etc.. so I shouldn't shift the data? how would the lstm predict the next output say t+1 if I'm feeding it the features and target at time t? shouldn't the target be t+1 for the features at time t? so that the loss for example can be computed as the mean squared error of the predicted output which is at t+1 and the target which should be also at t+1?

Comment: This is why you need to understand how they work first. The input to a node of an LSTM includes the current timestep and the output of the previous time step

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ take a look here, he also shifted the data somehow to use it later with LSTM